# ¿Por que me crea una cookie con nombre ASP.NET_SessionId?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, cookies

Tengo un proyecto en ASP.NET MVC 5 en el cual al revisar las `cookies` de mi aplicacion aparece una que se llama `ASP.NET_SessionId`, la cual no se para que es y por que se crea.

¿Alguien sabe algo acerca de esta `cookie`?

Comment: lectura obligatoria: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: Pero eso habla del AntiForygenToken la cual la cookie que crea es __RequestVerificationToken, pero y la cookie  ASP.NET_SessionId de donde viene y para que sirve.

Comment: lectura obligatoria parte 2: https://forums.asp.net/t/1491107.aspx?ASP+NET_SessionId+Cookie :D

Answer (score 1):

Es la cookie que genera ASP.NET para las sesiones.

Puedes desactivar esa cookie agregando `<%@ EnableSessionState=False %>` al comienzo de la pagina aspx

Comment: ¿Supongo que de igual forma serviria en ASP.NET MVC 5? ¿Y si coloco esta linea de codigo no podria utilizar las session en esa pagina correcto?

Comment: Correcto. Es una propiedad de ASP.NET independientemente de si es MVC o Webform